# How do I display a double in an af:inputText rounded down to an integer?

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I have an `af:inputText` which displays a double value. For example: 17555.8

```
<af:inputText value="#{bindings.regnum.inputValue}"
     disabled="true"
     simple="true" id="it4"/>
```

I want to view this data as an integer: 17555. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<af:inputText value="#{bindings.regnum.inputValue}" disabled="true" simple="true" id="it4">
<af:convertNumber type="number" messageDetailConvertNumber="#"/>
</af:inputText>
```

More about convertNumber [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_convertNumber.html)